# Не сбрасываются отступы на главной странице

Tags: html, css

У меня не сбрасываются отступы на главной странице:

```
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Разрабатываю  сайт на локальной машине. На главной странице (localhost) сбрасывание не срабатывает, a на остальных страницах работает. 
На главной странице мой container(первый потомок body) имеет расстояние сверху между браузером и собой. На остальных страницах container прилипает к верху окна браузера. Вот и скачет макет то вверх то вниз при переходе с главной на др. страницу и наоборот. Страницы формируются динамически, если это имеет значение. Для всех страниц используется один и тот же макет index.php

Если кто знает как решить эту странность отзовитесь пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: правой кнопкой на странице - инспектировать элемент. смотрите что у вас для body задано реально. скорее всего ваши маржины и/или паддинги перекрываются где-то ниже.

Comment: Ничем не перекрываются. Даже если бы перекрывалось это правило должно было бы работать на всех страницах. Еще раз повторюсь, что для всех страниц используется один и тот же макет index.php. В этом и заключается странность моего случая. Ума не приложу в чем причина.

Comment: Учтите еще такую фигню, что если первый потомок body иммет margin-top (ну и без абсолютного позиционирования, разумеется), то в браузерах (FF, Chrome, Opera точно) выглядит так, словно это body имеет внутренний отступ (padding-top) равный margin-top дочернего элемента

Comment: Масло масленое))

Comment: код по ходу мы не видим - гадание на кофейной гуще ну или да, на масле масляном.

Comment: @z_coder, вырастешь - поймешь ;)

_________


http://jsfiddle.net/g3Gya/2/ - нормальный вариант, у body padding: 10px,
http://jsfiddle.net/g3Gya/1/ - у внутреннего блока margin 10px, но этот отстцп считается от начала документа, а не от body, "рамки" серого цвета нет, хотя по логике должна быть, ведь #main отступает от body из-за margin на 10px.


_________


Более доступно уже точно не обьясню

Answer (score 1):

[надеюсь это поможет](http://ktonanovenkogo.ru/html/uroki-css/padding-margin-border-css-top-bottom-left-right-html.html)

Comment: Это не как не может мне помочь

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у вас где-то в css-ке указаны еще раз отступы для этого блока. Проверьте.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. У меня нет никаких отступов для этого блока. В том то и дело даже если бы и был бы, то он должен был бы сработать на всех страницах. Макет то один.

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Не работает. Это то же самое.

Comment: Решил проблему. Оказывается надо было просто проставить декларацию в bootstrap file index.php. В противном случае firefox на главной странице выдавал старый добрый quirks mode.